# cannot find module 'jspdf-autotable' and 'jspdf' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

mycomponent.ts

```
import  jsPDF  from 'jspdf';
import autoTable from 'jspdf-autotable';

export class Component implements OnInit {
.
.
.
 exportPdf() {

    const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
 columns = [...]

    autoTable(doc, {
      columns: this.columns,
      body: this.data,
      didDrawPage: (dataArg) => {
        doc.text('data', dataArg.settings.margin.left, 10);
      }
    });
    doc.save('data.pdf');
  }
}
```

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {

    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.23"

}
```

I installed my npm packages with npm i jspdf and npm i jspdf-autotable but the same errors persist. I don't understand what should I do. Are the versions wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install `@types/jspdf` and `@types/jspdf-autotable` as dev-dependencies.

If you use `yarn`:

```
yarn add -D @types/jspdf @types/jspdf-autotable
```

For `npm` use:

```
npm install @types/jspdf @types/jspdf-autotable --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

npm install jspdf jspdf-autotable

for any dependency error execute below statement

npm install jspdf jspdf-autotable --force